# how to create a file sytem monitor to catch every change made to a file

Tags: python, linux, windows, file, filesystems

I want to create a file system monitor which will notify whenever a change is made to any file on the file system, especially a write, new file creation or rename.

I have done research, and found stuff like `FindFirstChangeNotification` function, pyinotify

How to access the log and use it to do the above?

Any file change will be then used by the software for further calculations, how to go about?

Platform : Windows(priority), Linux

Comment: This is way too broad. Those two platforms are totally different. What you need to do is write a driver.

Comment: can you please give me a way to do it only for windows....jus the way to go about it

Comment: You need to write a driver. First step is to learn about that.

Comment: is FindFirstChangeNotification function of any help ??

Comment: Not really. That will allow you to watch a single folder. And it's not robust. You won't pick up all modifications. You can't expect to watch all folders.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog), it's a python library for monitoring file systems and works on both Linux and Windows.

import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    # you may need to use path='c:\' for windows below
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='/', recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

You would want to replace `LoggingEventHandler` with your own class which derives from [`FileSystemEventHandler`](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#event-handler-classes), implementing `on_created`, `on_modified`, etc.

Finally please note that watching every file on the entire system may lead you into scalability issues. You'd be better to try and narrow down what you want to monitor.

Comment: I can't imagine that could observe every single file system event across an entire system. Or could it?

Comment: It can, if you set path='/' and recursive=True it'll do just that. Internally it's recursively walking the whole filesystem and setting a monitor up for each file and directory. When new files and directories are created it detects this and adds more monitors.

Comment: I can't believe that would be viable. A separate monitor for every object in the file system.

Comment: It's non-ideal, but very much workable. The scalability issues are discussed in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535768/what-is-a-reasonable-amount-of-inotify-watches-with-linux

Comment: Not sure I would call that workable at all. In comparison to the trivial overhead of a filter at the driver level.

Comment: If it works for his application, I'd say that's *far* more trivial than writing a driver.

Comment: I agree with David Hefferman, no application/library that works in user mode could not things that kernel mode drivers do.

Comment: Also from watchdog doc I assume for Windows use ReadDirectoryChanges wrapper. So many notifications from AV soft or malware will be hidden.